# linux start time and stop timer is not working ?

Tags: c, linux, timer, timertask

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;

#define million 1000000L

long duration2ms, duration10ms, duration100ms;
double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster;
timer_t firstTimerID, secondTimerID, thirdTimerID;

void TASK1(Task2ms_Raster) {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    int a, b, c;
    uint32 StartTime, StopTime;
    a=100, b=2;

    if((StartTime = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    printf("start time is= %ld\n", StartTime);
    //I am performing some computation like 
    a = a + 100;
    b = a + 120;
    a = a + b;
    b = a;
    c = b;
      if((StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }

 printf("stop time is= %ld\n", StopTime);

    duration2ms = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                  (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) /
                  (double)million;
    printf("time difference is= %ld\n", duration2ms);
}
```

I created the timer and calling the task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. The above is the code for 2ms task. I want to calculate the start time and stop time for performing some computation within the task and finally want to know the time difference between that. when I run my application, it is just displaying the time difference (i.e duration2ms). It is not printing the StartTime and StopTime. Could someone please help me.

Comment: Try adding a fflush(stdout) before the last }.  The task is possibly dying before everything has been flushed.

Comment: @cup, no need for that, at the end of normal execution all output buffers are flushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the manual page of `clock_gettime` you would see that

> clock_gettime() return 0 for success, or -1 for failure.

So, you are printing the return code only. To print start time and stop time you will need to print the content of variables `start` and `stop`. For example:

```
   printf("Start time: %d.%09d\n", start.tv_sec, start.tv_nsec);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. Is it possible to store it in a variable as StartTime ?? could you please tell me how to do this??

Comment: `double StartTime; ... StartTime = start.tv_sec + 0.000001 * start.tv_nsec;`

Comment: Sorry. shall be 0.000000001. The value is in nano seconds. I used to use `struct timeval` which is in microsecnds.

Comment: The time is represented by two values: `.tv_sec` which is the number of seconds since midnight 1.1.1970 and `.tv_nsec` which is the number of nanoseconds since the last second. To combine them into a single number you have either to multiply `.tv_sec` by `1e9`, or to divide `.tv_nsec` by `1e9`.

Comment: after calculating the StartTime and StopTime : duration2ms = StopTime -StartTime ; //Is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

what u need is

```
uint64_t u64StartTime = (start.tv_sec * 100000000) + start.tv_nsec;
```